# How do I count letters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written this function (which is not working) which is supposed to count the letters in a global variable (`paraText`), and then insert it to count. How do I solve this?

This is a school project so I have to follow sertain rules. I have tried almost all answers but I can't get it to work :( maybe if you look at all the code you can see what I'm doing wrong.

```
        "use strict";

    var paraText = "";
    var antalParagrafer = 0;

    function addLetter(c) {
        if(!paraText) {
            addParagraph();
        }
        else { //add c to saved textnode
            var tNod = document.createTextNode(c);
            paraText.appendChild(tNod);
    }
    }
        //function is called when enter is pressed
    function addParagraph() {
 /*create a new paragraph with related textnode
    textnode is saved to the global textnodevariable
    add paragraph to the div with id "output"
    you also need to mark the paragraph with the class even/odd
    depending on the class of the previous paragraph*/
        var div = document.getElementById("output");
        var nyParagraf = document.createElement("p");
        div.appendChild(nyParagraf);
        antalParagrafer += 1;
        nyParagraf.className = (antalParagrafer % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd');
        paraText = nyParagraf;
    }
    //function is called when count letters is pressed
           function countLetters() {
      var count=0;
      for(var i = 0; i < paraText.length; i++) {
        var c = paraText.charAt(i);
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') count++;
      }
      return count;
    }
```

Comment: Off-topic suggestion: Instead of making this function dependent on a global variable, add a parameter to its definition (e.g. `function countLetters(text)`) and then count the letters contained in that argument (i.e., in `text` instead of `paraText`). This costs very little, but makes your function more versatile.

Answer (score 9):

I'd just strip out the non-letters and then use the length of what's left:

```
var count = paraText.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').length;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your function works otherwise fine (although it's perhaps not as elegant as it could be), but `count = count ++` is wrong; either use

```
count++;
```

or

```
count = count + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement `count = count++` doesn't increase the counter, because the value of `count++` is what's in the variable before it is increased, so you increse the variable, then assign back the value that was before.

Using a simple comparison gives better performance than using a regular expression for each character in the string:

```
function countLetters() {
  var count=0;
  for(var i = 0; i < paraText.length; i++) {
    var c = paraText.charAt(i);
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it to work, I have change the question at the top of the page so please look there for mor info.

Comment: @Eric: The function works, with the assumption that it is a string, as indicated by the original code. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/F5fNV/ The reason that your code doesn't work is that the variable is not a string, but an HTML element. Use one variable for the HTML element, and one string variable where you collect only the texts.

Comment: I took out the 2 functions between and wrote a string i paratext and it worked great, so why doesn't it work with the 2 other functions? What am I doing wrong.

Comment: @Eric: The paraText variable contains an HTML element, and you try to use it like a string. Store the element in one variable and a copy of the text in another variable, and use that variable when you count the letters.

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot, I have tried to do as you told me but I can't get it to work. I added the coments from school so you can see how they want it to be.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, and a special thanx to Guffa that got me from a complete idiot to accually solving it :) .